# Angular universal debugging and stack trace

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, zone

I'm currently struggling to implement angular universal in an existing project. I removed all third party packages to make it compile and running. But when loading the website there is still a runtime error I cannot make any sense of:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Observable._subscribe (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:4918989)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:1857157)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:1856939)
    at C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:1857899
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:2078393)
    at Observable.toPromise (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:1857820)
    at C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:135208
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:3647694)
    at _next (C:\Users\Src\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:1:3647997)
```

How can I debug angular server properly in general to get a stack trace from the mapped sources?